# como selecionar a linha inteira de um JTable usando DefaultCellRenderer que muda a cor da linha

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Olá, estou trabalhando com JTables e, em tal JTable eu precisei deixar algumas linhas em cores diferenciadas, então implementei o método

```
class cellRenderModel extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

ModelCartao mCard;

public cellRenderModel(ModelCartao mc) {
    this.mCard = mc;
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    Color c = Color.WHITE;
    if (mCard.isCor(row)) {//Verifica se é para pintar ou não (funcionando perfeitamente!)
        c = Color.GREEN;
        label.setBackground(c);
    } else {
        c = Color.WHITE;
        label.setBackground(c);
    }
    return label;
}
}
```

E deixei como defaultRender da tabela

```
minhaTabela.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class,new cellRenderModel(mCard));
```

O problema:

antes da implementação desse método, conforme selecionava o JTable, ele selecionava toda a linha (deixar em azul a linha selecionada), como é o padrão do JTable. Porém, depois de formatado como descrito, ele perdeu essa característica, gostaria que voltasse como antes, que ele selecionasse a linha inteira conforme clica ou aperta para cima ou para baixo.

E outro problema: quando clico na tabela, mostra um "foco" na célula, como um azul um pouco mais emblemático do que a seleção comum, em torno de tal célula, mas quando a tabela perde o foco, essa característica também some, voltando apenas quando ganha o foco novamente, gostaria de fazer isso aparecer sempre. e se possível, mudar também.

OBS: já tentei adicionar esse mouseListener mas não funcionou:

```
minhaTabela.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            int row = minhaTabela.getSelectedRow();
            int col = minhaTabela.getSelectedColumn();
            tbFin.setRowSelectionInterval(row,row);
            tbFin.setColumnSelectionInterval(col,col);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    });
```

aqui estão as "configurações" da minha JTable:

```
tb.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    tb.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    tb.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    tb.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
    tb.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    tb.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    tb.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new celRenderModel(mCard));
    tb.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
    tb.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
```

Desde Já, agradeço!

Comment: Isso aqui não me parece certo: `JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);` Qual a necessidade disso?

Comment: isso serve para tratar a célula em específico como um JLabel, facilitando a maneira de deixar o background de cor diferente

Comment: Para selecionar uma linha inteira e unica, basta um `suaTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);`

Comment: estava com MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION, mudei para a sua dica, não fez diferença :/

Comment: eu coloquei as "configurações" da minha JTable na dúvida, espero que isso ajude a saber o que estou fazendo de errado

Comment: Recomendo que altere a primeira linha do seu renderer, deixe o super isolado. Faça o teste para ver se volta a funcionar.

Comment: Não sei se foi isso que você sugeriu, mas seguindo "mais ou menos" a sua lógica de raciocínio, eu consegui resolver, vou postar o código como resposta, valeu mesmo Diego!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maneira que eu encontrei para resolver meu problema:

```
class celRenderModel extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

ModelCartao mCard;

public celRenderModel(ModelCartao mc) {
    this.mCard = mc;
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

    Color c = Color.WHITE;
    if (mCard.isCor(row)) {//Verifica se é para pintar ou não (funcionando perfeitamente!)
        c = Color.GREEN;
        setBackground(c);
    } else {
        c = Color.WHITE;
        setBackground(c);
    }
    return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
}
}
```

espero que isso ajude quem estiver com essa mesma dúvida!!!

Comment: Na verdade, você pode remover o super na primeira linha do método, pois você já o está acionando no return, vai continuar funcionando. do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Funcionou também, vou editar a resposta, valeu a dica!!

Answer (score 0):

Você já tentou `setRowSelectionAllowed(true)` em sua JTable instância?

Eu lhe sugiro a dar uma olhada na documentação do Java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSelectionAllowed(boolean)

E também ler este tutorial sbore os componentes Table no Java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Espero que isto tenha lhe ajudado :)

Comment: Agradeço, mas já estava com o setRowSelectionAllowed(true), como eu disse, antes de eu adicionar o DefaultRenderer funcionava a seleção normalmente, mas após adicionar, complicou um pouco

Comment: e quanto aos links, agradeço, mas já li esses dois links umas 30x para fazer esse projeto, e estava tudo ocorrendo bem, até agora :/

Answer (score 0):

É simples. Apague essas linhas abaixo. Uma delas deve ter sido criada automaticamente pela IDE na construção da tabela:

jTable.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

OU
      jTable.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

OU

jTable.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

Fazendo isso, a linha inteira passa a ser selecionada.